# Cannot read property 'someFunction' of null for 'someFunction' within onClick

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering a list of items retrieved from Firebase. For each item, I render a div, that includes a button that removes said item.

Relevant code:

```
constructor(props){
    // Pass props to parent class
    super(props);

    this.removeItem = this.removeItem.bind(this);
    this.getList = this.getList.bind(this); 
    ...
}

removeItem(key) {
    this.ref(key).remove()
}

getList() {
    var list = []
    this.ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
            list.push(<div class="todo-item">{snapshot.val()[key]} <button onClick={() => this.removeItem(key)}> X </button> </div>)
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });
    return(list)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div class="todolist">
            .....
            {this.getList()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The list of items and their remove buttons renders fine. However, when clicking the remove button, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeItem' of null`

As `removeItem` is a function of `this`, I assume that `this` is not properly bound and thus `null`.

However, I bound both functions `removeItem` and `getList` in the constructor.

Does someone know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most common problem of `context` being lost when `this` is accessed from anonymous function.

To get around this,

Use arrow functions:

```
this.ref.on("value", (snapshot) => { ... }, (error) => { ... });
```

OR
Use `bind(this)`

```
this.ref.on("value", function (snapshot) { ... }.bind(this), function (error) { ... }.bind(this));
```